# Unencrypted equivalent of SSH reverse proxy

Tags: linux, networking, mac-osx, tcpip

I'm looking for an equivalent of this:

```
ssh -R 8888:10.0.0.2:8888 100.101.102.103
```

ie. make the service running on port 8888 on the local machine (10.0.0.2) look like a locally running service on a remote machine (100.101.102.103).

However, I don't want the encryption overhead of ssh, since the service in question is https and is thus already encrypted.

Can anyone suggest a tool to do this? Note that the direction of the initiation is important here - ie. it's the equivalent of a *reverse* tunnel. The local machine, where the service is running, is on a private network and not directly visible to the remote machine; the remote machine has a public IP though.

- unix (OS X and Linux) on each end
- I have full access to both machines

Comment: Google for: "tcp gender change". An article on Wikipedia: en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Gender_Changer. Some tools which do that on Linux: tgcd, revinetd

Answer (score 8):

A pair of netcat sessions would fit the bill, I guess.

man nc

Comment: It would be nice to see an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Just set ssh's encryption cypher to none.

```
ssh -c none -R 8888:10.0.0.2:8888 100.101.102.103
```

Comment: Not possible on most platforms without the use of a third-party patch.

Comment: Probably just as well, it really does nerf the secure bit of ssh.

Answer (score 4):

do not forget socat, the swiss army knife of network forwarders ;)

http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/

Comment: Nice ! I didn't know it.

Comment: It would be nice to see an example of how to use it to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

I have used [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) for this in the past with great success.

rinetd is a very small, stable, and simple program that listens for 
incoming connections and forwards them, the configuration is really 
simple

```
# bindadress    bindport  connectaddress  connectport
1.2.3.4         80        4.3.2.1         80
1.2.3.4         443       4.3.2.1         443
```

There is also a program called "[stone](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/stone/)" that can do the same:
Example... http forward from the gateway to an internal machine (1.2.3.4):

```
$ stone 1.2.3.4:80 80
```

Answer (score 2):

An inetd combined with netcat should do the trick. See [Forwarding Ports](http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/netcat_inhalt.en.html#ToC4), although xinetd may be a better choice these days.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of firewall rule? Something in `iptables` to redirect one port to another?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to use smells like NAT Port Forwarding to me. One iptables rules and it's done.